# After decryption the png file is corrupted

Tags: c++, encryption, png

I have a project and I am working on encrypting and decrypting files on the disk. I have worked to read a file character by character and store it in string obj. After that I apply xor encryption and then Base64 encryption. Now I am facing problem while decrypting it. I am trying to decrypt it and store it in the disk, but it is not opening. It shows error the file is corrupted. When I open the input image and output image *as txt* both have same data in them. I know I am doing many things wrong but I have no experience and I am student of BS 1st semester. The code is below.

```
#include<iostream>
#include<string>
#include<fstream>
#include<Base64.h>
using namespace macaron;
using namespace std;

string xor_(string ch){
    int i =0, count = ch.size();
    string str="";
    char c,n;
    while (i<count){
        c = ch[i];
        n = c^'p';
        str = str+n;
        i++;
        }
    return str;
}

int main(){
    ifstream f("save.png", ios::binary | ios::in);
    char c,n,p;
    string cs1="";
    int count=1;
    // Reading file character by character and storing it in cs1 string datatype variable
    while(f.get(c)){
        count++;
        cs1 = cs1+c;
    }
    // Encrypting cs1 with xor method       
    string encrypted = xor_(cs1);
    // Encrypted string further encrypted using base64
    string encoded_string = Base64::Encode(encrypted);
    //Replacing the encrypted file
    std::ofstream out("save.txt");
    out << encoded_string;
    out.close();
    string decoded;        
    Base64::Decode(encoded_string,decoded);
    string decrypted = xor_(decoded);
    std::ofstream out1("save2.png");
    out1 << decrypted;
    out1.close();
    //cout<<decrypted<<endl;
    cout<<(cs1==decrypted);
    return 0;
}
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You read *binary* data, but you write *text* data.

Comment: Also don't try to treat raw bytes as characters. While `std::string` can hold arbitrary bytes it's not its purpose. Please use `std::vector<std::byte>` (or `std::vector<std::uint8_t>` if you don't have `std::byte`) instead.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude Will the code work for std Byte vector?. I do not know about vectors yet but will study and try. Will Also check how to write in binary. If you can help more, it will be great.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude Thanks Writing in binary mode worked. Make a answer, I would accept it and give 3 upvote